# Config debezium content-based routing in confluent kafka connect container

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I use kafka connect to replicate database from postgres db to mongo db. I config content-based routing follow the [docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/content-based-routing.html). When i call api to regester source connector to kafka connect, it throws exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.DebeziumException`.

Is possible use debezium content-based routing in confluent kafka connect container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> possible use debezium content-based routing in confluent kafka connect container

Not without adding the Debezium JAR files on the contiainer's CLASSPATH. By default, these images have no Debezium (or MongoDB) code installed.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is resolved. I placed all jar files (include: ```debezium-* jar```, ```groovy-* jar```) in one place. And all ```debezium* jar``` files should be aligned by version.